# how to display an image from second page in dom pdf?

Tags: php, dompdf

I am new to dom pdf. I am loading footer image in all the pdf pages using DOM pdf.and banner image only in first page of pdf.

From second page i want to display another image in header part.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header and footer you use is DOM PDF are on every page the same. If you want to have different images on each page you can use your own css to archieve this.

If you only want page 1 to be different, you need to take a look [here].([dompdf: How to add header on every page except first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211256/dompdf-how-to-add-header-on-every-page-except-first)). That question is already treated.