# How can ignore header form first page only

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am generate pdf using ' "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4" ' in laravel and i am adding header in pdf but it is showing now on each page of pdf but i no need to that header on first page only. So help me ignore header form first page.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have used to generate the pdf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dompdf: How to add header on every page except first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211256/dompdf-how-to-add-header-on-every-page-except-first)