# Dompdf Laravel Library cannot show footer in all pages

Tags: css, laravel, dompdf

I am generating a pdf of my quotation form in Laravel by using DomPDF library. Mostly quotations are more than 1 pages so I want to repeat my footer content (logo and some text) on all pages. Currently footer appears only on last page whereas I want to show it on all pages. Any solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dompdf: How to add header on every page except first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211256/dompdf-how-to-add-header-on-every-page-except-first)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Header in PDF page using DOMPDF in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484318/header-in-pdf-page-using-dompdf-in-php)

Comment: no for both questions